# TikZ / foreach: read out sequence of Unicode symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontspec, unicode, foreach

How can I read out `\char"1F0A1,...,\char"1F0DF` 
that means `\char127137, ..., \char127199` 
with a foreach-loop?

I got `Dimensions too large` if I use the second version; and TikZ does not like hexadecimal numbers at the first version.

***Does TikZ know a solution here or is that only possible with other things?***

Hint: By using the font `Segoe UI Symbol` or `DejaVu Sans` this should give the [*unicode play card symbols:*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode)
[image]

**Test-MWE with incorrect numbers:**

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}
\section{Test:}

\foreach[evaluate={  \LineBreak=(  int( mod(\n-1,13) ) },
evaluate={  \Seperator=(  \LineBreak==12 ? "." : ",~")  }
] \n in {14,...,78}{%% <--- here are not the correct numbers... 
\myfont\char"\n      \Seperator \ifnum\LineBreak=12 \\ \fi 
}%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\foreach \n in {0,...,64}{\myfont\char\inteval{\n+127137}}`

Comment: works......... :()

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Why not making an answer from that?

Comment: @egreg says the same at the begin of his answer only with  \numexpr instead of \inteval, which is faster but not so modern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may probably get away with a `\foreach` loop from 37 to 99, using arithmetic for printing the right glyph

```
\char\numexpr127100+\n\relax
```

Here's a different loop; note that the playing cards block has sixteen slots for each suit.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\cardfont{DejaVu Sans}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\intstep}{m O{1} m +m}
 {% #1 = start, #2 = step, #3 = end, #4 = action
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\actionmodulo}{m m +m +m}
 {% #1 = integer to test, #2 = modulo, #3 = normal action, #4 = action at multiples of #1
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } == 0 } { #4 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{step}

\begin{document}

\intstep{"1F0A1}{"1F0DF}{%
  {\cardfont\symbol{#1}}%
  \stepcounter{step}%
  \actionmodulo{\value{step}}{16}{, }{.\par}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may modify the loop to discard the unwanted slots.

Comment: Eh...? Sixteen what?  A, K, Q, J, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3,  2 und K (Knight)  makes 14? What is still missing?

Comment: @cis Ask the Unicode people: there are J and C (probably for taking into account different national conventions) and one or two reserved slots after each block. At the end of the diamonds block there's the red joker and one reserved slots; similarly at the end of the clubs block.

Comment: Eh, I saw,  it is C = Knight (e.g. C♥ 'Knight Heart'). So I think the addition is Knight, "Star Card" (?) -as I see in your picture- and Joker for each suit (?).